# Como cambiar el valor de un campo antes de guardar según la fecha actual

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

*Puede que el titulo sea poco claro, y pido disculpas por ello, ya que buscaba un titulo que no fuera muy extenso.*

Resulta que tengo en mi controlador en laravel una función completa que me guarda múltiples registros el cual desde una vista obtengo los datos a guardar en una tabla llamada **horario**.

Resulta que tengo un campo, en dicha tabla, el cual establece el estado del horario de unas reservas entre activo e inactivo dependiendo de la fecha inicial escogida. Y lo que busco es que al momento de ir **insertando** los registros cuando dentro del recorrido llegue a la fecha actual el campo del estado del horario cambie de Inactivo a Activo.

Por ejemplo, para que se entienda:

Se escogió el siguiente rango de fechas: `2019-01-01 08:00:00` - `2019-01-23 23:00:00`, entre 2 input (fechas) y 2 select (horarios)

Y al momento de guardar en la base de datos los primeros 330 registros deberían quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
 id|hora_inicio        |hora_inicio        |estado_horario_id
  1|2019-01-01 08:00:00|2019-01-01 09:00:00|                1
  2|2019-01-01 09:00:00|2019-01-01 10:00:00|                1
...
330|2019-22-01 22:00:00|2019-22-01 23:00:00|                1
```

Y los siguientes 15 registros como para este caso corresponden a la fecha actual, deberían quedar de la siguiente manera, tomando en cuenta la hora también:

```
 id|hora_inicio        |hora_fin           |estado_horario_id
331|2019-23-01 08:00:00|2019-23-01 09:00:00|                1
332|2019-23-01 09:00:00|2019-23-01 10:00:00|                1
333|2019-23-01 10:00:00|2019-23-01 11:00:00|                1
...
336|2019-23-01 13:00:00|2019-23-01 14:00:00|                2
337|2019-23-01 14:00:00|2019-23-01 15:00:00|                2
...
345|2019-23-01 22:00:00|2019-23-01 23:00:00|                2
```

El cual al llegar a la **fecha y hora actual** cambie de **Inactivo (1)** a **Activo (2).** Y para fechas futuras se mantenga en Activo (2).

De momento en una funcion en javascript establecí que el campo del estado del horario, cambie según la fecha escogida.

```
<input type="date" name="horario[{{$last_horario['id']}}][desde]"  id="desde" onchange="ModificaEstadoHorario()" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ModificaEstadoHorario(){

        var fechaElegida = new Date(desde.value);
        var actual = new Date();

        if(fechaElegida.toISOString().substring(0, 10) < actual.toISOString().substring(0, 10)){

            document.getElementById('estado_horario_id').value = 'Inactiva';
        }else{
            document.getElementById('estado_horario_id').value = 'Activa';
        }
     }
<script>

<input type="text" value="Activa" name="horario[{{$last_horario['id']}}][estado_horario_id]" id="estado_horario_id">
```

Esto es parte del formulario completo y debido a que es extenso solo coloqué ese código para no alargar mucho la pregunta.

Ahora en mi controlador rescato la informacion enviada por el formulario, de la siguiente manera.

*Atención con los comentarios.*

```
public function store(Request $request){

    try {
        /*CON EL SIGUIENTE CÓDIGO SE LOGRA GUARDAR MÚLTIPLES HORARIOS*/

        foreach($request->horario as $id_horario=>$row){    
            foreach($row['check'] as $check){


                $startdate = $row['desde'];
                $endate = $row['hasta'];

                $period = CarbonPeriod::create($startdate, $endate); // Creamos un objeto "periodo" propio de Carbon
                $period_2 = CarbonPeriod::create($startdate, $endate);

                $dates = $times = []; // Variables para almacenar las fechas y los horarios
                $dates_2 = $times_2 = [];

                $tstart = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $row['hora_inicio']); /*Creamos una instancia de carbon para la hora de inicio*/
                $tend = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $row['hora_termino']); /*Y otra instancia para la hora de finalización*/

                $tstart_2 = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $row['hora_inicio']);
                $tstart_2->modify('+1 hour');

                $tend_2 = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $row['hora_termino']);

                while ($tstart < $tend){ // Mientras la hora de inicio sea menor a la hora de finalización

                    $times[] = $tstart->format("H:i:s"); // Agregamos esa hora al array de los horarios
                    $tstart->addHour(); // Luego aumentamos en 1 hora 
                }
                while ($tstart_2 <= $tend_2){

                    $times_2[] = $tstart_2->format('H:i:s');
                    $tstart_2->addHour();
                }
                foreach($period as $date){ // Recorremos todas las fechas generadas en el periodo
                    foreach($times as $time){ // Así como los horarios generados en el while anterior

                        $dates[] = $date->format("Y-m-d") . " " . $time; // Y lo concatenamos y guardamos en el array de las fechas
                    }
                }
                foreach ($period_2 as $date_2) {
                    foreach ($times_2 as $time_2) {

                        $dates_2[] = $date_2->format('Y-m-d'). " ".$time_2;
                    }
                }

                $cuenta = count($dates);



            //AQUI ES EN DONDE INTENTO ESTABLECER LO DICHO ANTERIORMENTE

            /*QUE SI LA FECHA ESCOGIDA ES MENOR QUE LA ACTUAL EL ESTADO
              DEL HORARIO CAMBIE DE ACTIVO A INACTIVO*/      

           /*PERO DE ESTA MANERA ME DEJA TODO EN INACTIVO YA QUE
             COMO EL VALOR CAMBIA SE MANTIENE ASÍ Y NO VUELVE A 
             CAMBIAR A - ACTIVO DESPUÉS QUE PASA LA FECHA Y HORA 
             ACTUAL*/
                if ($row['estado_horario_id'] == 'Activa') {

                    $row['estado_horario_id'] = 2;

                }else if ($row['estado_horario_id'] == 'Inactiva'){

                    $row['estado_horario_id'] = 1;
                }


                for($i = 0; $i < $cuenta; $i++){

                    $horarios[]= [
                        'hora_incio' => $dates[$i],
                        'hora_fin' => $dates_2[$i],
                        'estado_horario_id' => $row['estado_horario_id'],
                        'cancha_id ' => $check
                    ];
                    HorariosNew::create(['hora_inicio' => $dates[$i],'hora_fin' => $dates_2[$i],'estado_horario_id' => $row['estado_horario_id'], 'cancha_id' => $check]);
                }
            }
        }
    }catch (\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {

         Session::flash('error', 'Hubo un error desconocido, no se pudo registrar el horario');
         return redirect()->route('horarios.store');
    }

    Session::flash('message', 'Se agregó correctamente el horario');
    return redirect()->route('horarios.store');     
}
```

Comment: A ver si entendí: dada una fecha/hora, quieres que en la tabla se actualicen los registros en la columna `estado_horario_id` según este criterio: todas las filas cuya columna ¿`hora_fin`? se igual o menor a la fecha/hora dada tomarán el valor `1` en `estado_horario_id`, de lo contrario, tomarán el valor `2` ... ¿Entendí bien?  Si entendí bien: supongo que haces un `UPDATE table SET  ...` ¿dónde está ese `UPDATE` y por qué no lo haces a través de esa consulta en vez de complicarte tanto?  Si no entendí bien: ¿puedes explicar el problema en un sólo párrafo 1º y luego das detalles si quieres?

Comment: En ningún momento hago un update, creo siempre los registros nuevos. Y mientras la función vaya recorriendo las fechas escogidas a la columna del estado del horario le establezca el valor de 1, pero para cuando al momento de llegar a la fecha actual con hora incluida, esa columna se guarde con valor 2 y se mantenga para fechas futuras. Eso deberia hacer, espero haberme explicado bien.

Comment: La explicación empieza bien, pero cuando pasamos al código hay tal embrollo en el mismo que me perdí. Creo que deberías explicar en resumen el contexto y luego muestras el código si quieres. No es fácil meterle mano a un código lleno de comentarios para ver si uno logra adivinar la lógica que otro ha implementado, más aún sin saber si esa lógica es la correcta o es precisamente la fuente del problema y debe ser cambiada. Por ejemplo no había entendido lo que acabas de decir, que insertas siempre los datos nuevos. Es un detalle importante y que es parte del contexto, el cual debe quedar claro.

Comment: Estás consciente que si tomas la referencia de fecha actual con javascript, se basará en la fecha del dispositivo cliente, es decir, que si en el cliente se cambia la fecha cambiará el resultado de estado_horario_id.

Creo que la mejor manera sería hacer un trigger en la base de datos para que después de cada insert consulte si la fecha insertada es igual o superior a la fecha actual del SERVIDOR, y así actualiza el campo estado_horario_id directo en la BD.

Comment: @A.Cedano. Es cierto que el código se ve confuso, para quienes no entienden el contexto, pero ese código como está funciona bien, solo intentaba agregarle una condicion más, la cual me cambiaba, ciertamente, el comportamiento de la función, pero no dejaba de funcionar, otro dato es que esa función se comporta de la misma manera como explicaba en un principio, así que si estoy en lo cierto no debería ser difícil de entender el contexto o si no me corrige si estoy equivocado.

Comment: @milo. Si eso que dices lo tengo bien claro (o al menos eso pienso) por eso intentaba en el controlador añadir una función que cambie dicho valor que establecí en una funcion en javascript, para cuando dentro del recorrido cambie el valor de 1 a 2 para el campo del estado del horario cuando la fecha se igual que la actual y se mantenga en 2 para futuras fechas.

Comment: Yo leí y traté de entender para ver si podía ayudarte, pero tal y como está la pregunta ahora lo veo difícil. Creo que en este tipo de preguntas hay que explicar 1º de una forma breve el contexto, en qué consiste la lógica que implementas y el resultado que obtienes. Así uno puede tener una idea y quizá decirse: *aquí falla la lógica*  y sugerirte: *¿por qué mejor no haces así o asá?*   o bien decir, *lógica OK*  y pasar a analizar el problema sobre el código. Esa es mi simple opinión para este tipo de preguntas. Pero soy uno entre muchos, quizá alguien con lo que aportas dé con la solución.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según lo que entiendo en tu código, bastaría con dejar el for donde hace el insert de la siguiente manera.

```
for($i = 0; $i < $cuenta; $i++){
  $estado_horario_id = 1; // se inicializa el estado en 1
  if( $dates[$i] >= Carbon::now()  ) { //*Leer comentario abajo* 
    $estado_horario_id = 2;
  }

  HorariosNew::create([
    'hora_inicio' => $dates[$i],
    'hora_fin' => $dates_2[$i],
    'estado_horario_id' => $estado_horario_id,
    'cancha_id' => $check]);
}
```

*Puede que tengas que revisar el formato entregado por Carbon para asegurarte que la comparación se realice bien.

Comment: Muchas gracias funciono, como esperaba. Solo modifiqué un detalle, no use una variable, en cambio utilice lo siguiente. if($dates[$i] >= Carbon::now()  ) {$row['estado_horario_id'] = 2;}`